# C - Basic Pointer questions

Tags: c, pointers

It has been a long time since I worked on C, so revisiting it now.

Can you help me with explaining what value does 'ptr' carry in below code ?

```
char str[] = "100";
char *ptr;
ptr = *str;
printf("\n %p \t %d \n", ptr, ptr);
```

Output shows:

0x31    49

I know that assigning *str to ptr is not correct, I'd however want to understand what that would actually mean. So what does 49 stand here ?

Comment: Your compiler was obligated to issue a diagnostic about this code. If it didn't, get a new compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is very forgiving in assigning values to variables of different kinds. That is why you don't get an error, even though you should!
So you are assigning `*str`, or, whatever `str` points to, to `ptr`. `str` is a char pointer, so it points to a char, in this case, the `'1'` in `"100"`.

That, then, is the value you assign to `ptr`, the value `'1'` or 49. (At least in an ASCII based system. On another system you would get a different value for `'1'`. For instance on an EBCDIC machine, `'1'` would be 241 instead of 49.)

And then you are trying to print the value of `ptr`, first as a pointer, which displays the numerical value of a pointer in hex, and then as a decimal, which simply displays the numerical value.

Now it's a good thing you're not trying to print `*ptr`, because that would have gone horribly wrong!

Comment: I did try to print *ptr and got a segmentation fault :) can you explain what *ptr in the above code would actually refer to ?

Comment: `*ptr` is that what ptr points to. But since it doesn't have a valid value, it doesn't point to anything useful. Most memory management systems can recognise if your process is dereferencing a memory location that you don't own, and give you a segmentation fault (as a failsafe device, really, not to punish you!) but you shouldn't count on that.

Answer (score 1):

49 is the ASCII code value for 1 which you are printing here using %d.

Since you're printing the value of element present in the first memory location of the array(ptr = *str = *str[0]), which is 1 here, so you get the ASCII value of 1 because of the %d.

Comment: How to print 1 instead of the Ascii character value ?

Comment: @user691197 - you should use %c to print the character value.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is not a char array, it is just a pointer, which points at the first memory location of the supposed array, just as @Am_I_Helpful said. And by writing `*str` you take value situated at the location where `str` points - which means you take the first value in the array.